# Preparing my software for an installer

Tags: google-chrome-extension, installation, firefox-addon, bundle

Which is the procedure I should follow in order to have my software (a browser extension/add-on) prepared to fit as many installers as possible. Specially those that Pay Per Install networks use to bundle software.

Should I create a PAD file?

Thanks!!